# Build Docker image of a Python Flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm trying to build a Docker image for a Python Flask app but having build problems - all files live in a folder called `web` - this is the project structure:

```
web/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    Dockerfile
    models.py
    requirements.txt
```

and `app.py` at the moment looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

I've borrrowed the `Dockerfile` from https://www.smartfile.com/blog/dockerizing-a-python-flask-application/:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip

# Add requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /webapp

# Install wsgi Python web server
RUN pip install uwsgi
# Install app requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp

# Expose port 8000 for uwsgi
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--module", "app:app", "--processes", "1", "--threads", "8"]
```

I'm trying to build the Docker image using `docker build --no-cache --rm -t flask-app`, but it ends with an error message:

```
Successfully installed uwsgi
Cleaning up...
 ---> 9bbc004212a3
Removing intermediate container 70ed8f07c408
Step 8/13 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in f5e2eb59ffd1
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a very small change on your Dockerfile would fix this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip

# Add requirements.txt
# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp

# Install wsgi Python web server
RUN pip install uwsgi
# Install app requirements
# Full path to requirements
RUN pip install -r /webapp/requirements.txt

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp

# Expose port 8000 for uwsgi
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--module", "app:app", "--processes", "1", "--threads", "8"]
```

I just added the full path to `requirements.txt`, this could be accomplished in several different ways, like copying the entire directory folder and then building it.

Comment: I get a similar error: `Successfully installed uwsgi
Cleaning up...
 ---> 42b208ea012c
Removing intermediate container 308ffeea1f10
Step 8/13 : RUN pip install -r /webapp/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in dbe480989f42
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/webapp/requirements.txt'
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /webapp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Do I have to physically create the `webapp` subdirectory inside the local `web` folder?

Comment: I moved the `ADD . /webapp` to above the `pip install` statement, can you try that out?

Comment: OK, it seems to have finished but with another error - `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py", line 415, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py", line 395, in setup_package

    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

----------------------------------------`. It seems this may be because `numpy` was not in requirements. I thought `scipy` would install any dependencies including `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the initial lines of the `Dockerfile` before adding requirements with

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

and it built the image successfully.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID                CREATED             SIZE
flask-app           latest              32b81efb5719        2 minutes ago       644.9 MB
ubuntu              latest              104bec311bcd        5 weeks ago         129 MB
$
$ docker run -d flask-app
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
73ae8baa93c2        flask-app       "uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        8000/tcp            lucid_heyrovsky
$
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 73ae8baa93c2
172.17.0.2
```

So when I try to point to the URL `http://172.17.0.2:8000/` I get nothing.

Comment: First of all you could check the `docker logs` for that container: make sure your Flask app is running. Next try to start the container with the `-p` option, to map the container port to the host, like so. `docker run -p 8000:8000 -d flask-app`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
WORKDIR /webapp
```

before

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```